# CPU usage is 100% during Thread.onSpinWait()

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, wait

I'm writing a backtesting raw data collector for my crypto trading bot and I've run into a weird optimization issue.

I constantly have 30 runnables in an Executors.newCachedThreadPool() running get requests from an API. Since the API has a request limit of 1200 per minute I have this bit of code in my runnable:

```
    while (minuteRequests.get() >= 1170) {
        Thread.onSpinWait();
    }
```

Yes, minuteRequests is an AtomicInteger, so I'm not running into any issues there.

Everything works, the issue is that even though I'm using the recommended busy-waiting onSpinWait method, I shoot from 24% CPU usage or so to 100% when the waiting is initiated. For reference I'm running this on a 3900X (24 thread).

Any recommendations on how to better handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation would be to not do busy waiting *at all*.

---

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait()) for `Thread.onSpinWait` say this:

> Indicates that the caller is momentarily unable to progress, until the occurrence of one or more actions on the part of other activities. By invoking this method within each iteration of a spin-wait loop construct, the calling thread indicates to the runtime that it is busy-waiting. The runtime **may take action to improve the performance of invoking spin-wait loop constructions**.

Note the highlighted section uses the word **may** rather than **will**.  That means that it also **may not** do anything.  Also "improve the performance" does not mean that your code will be objectively efficient.

The javadoc also implies that the improvements may be hardware dependent.

In short, this is the right way to use `onSpinwait` ... but you are expecting too much of it.  It won't make your busy-wait code efficient.

---

So what would I recommend you actually do?

I would recommend that you replace the `AtomicInteger` with a `Semaphore` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)).  This particular loop would be replaced by the following:

```
semaphore.acquire();
```

This blocks<sup>1</sup> until 1 "permit" is available and acquires it.  Refer to the class javadocs for an explanation of how semaphores work.

Note: since you haven't show us the complete implementation of your rate limiting, it is not clear how your current approach actually works.  Therefore, I can't tell you exactly how to replace `AtomicInteger` with `Semaphore` throughout.

---

<sup>1 - The blocked thread is "parked" until some other thread releases a permit.  While it is parked, the thread does not run and is not associated with a CPU core.  The core is either left idle (typically in a low power state) or it is assigned to some other thread.  This is typically handled by the operating system's thread scheduler.  When another thread releases a permit, the `Semaphore.release` method will tell the OS to unpark one of the threads that is blocked in `acquire`.</sup>

Comment: Not only did it solve the issue but looks a whole lot nicer as well imo. Would you mind explaing what "blocking" in this context does differently and why it doesnt eat up CPU time? From what I understood it has to do with the difference between a parked and a waiting thread?

Comment: @PressFToMakeGames there is no difference between parked and waiting. Your loop is just code which executed when the thread is *runnable*, not blocked and not waiting.